# Where does "logic" go? Blocks and accessing Models

Tags: module, model, ce-1.9.1.0

Let's say I have a custom Admin module that simply checks the magento database for cache settings. I want to pull the results to the page I created in admin.

I have a view in /design/adminhtml/default/default/templates/upgradecheck/view.phtml
I have the layout file in /design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/upgradecheck.xml

and then I have my custom module (Myname_Upgradecheck).

Everything "works" - as in when I load that page, it displays exactly the text I would expect (e.g. "1 cache is enabled"). My question is, did I do this correctly? Should the logic be in another file that just returns how many cache types are enabled and then call that function from the block? How exactly would I do that if that needs to be done?

```
class Myname_Upgradecheck_Block_Adminhtml_Upgradecheck extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template {
public function showCacheCount()
{
    $cachecheck = Mage::getModel('upgradecheck/cachecheck')->getCollection();
    $check = array();
    foreach($cachecheck as $cache){
        if ($cache->getValue() != 0) {
            array_push($check, $cache->getCode());
        }
    }
    if (count($check) != 0) {
        return count($check) . ' caches are enabled';
    }
    return 'No cache types are enabled';
}
```

}

In my view.phtml file I just have: `echo $this->showCacheCount();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks somehow OK. It works but it's not very clean.
Since you need only the number of enabled caches I would do it a bit differently (does not mean I'm doing it right).

I assume that `upgradecheck/cachecheck` is a custom model that maps on a table and that table has a column called `value`.
In this case you don't need to load the full collection and check each entity for the `value` field.
You can get directly the number of records with `value` not 0 like this:

```
class Myname_Upgradecheck_Block_Adminhtml_Upgradecheck extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template {
    public function getEnabledCacheCount()
    {
        $cachecheck = Mage::getModel('upgradecheck/cachecheck')->getCollection();
        $cachecheck->addFieldToFilter('value', array('neq' => 0)); //this will filter only the records with value != 0.
        //now you can get directly the size of the collection;
        return $cachecheck->getSize();
    }
}
```

And in your template you can do this:

```
<?php $enabledCacheCount = $this->getEnabledCacheCount() ?>
<?php if ($enabledCacheCount > 0) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('%d caches are enabled', $enabledCacheCount)?> <!-- make use of the translation function -->
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('No cache types are enabled')?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I know that the template in this form contains only php code, but now you can easily add some markup around the messages. for example a `<span class="green">` for when there are caches enabled and `<span class="red">` for when there are no caches enabled.
This way you separate the logic from the presentation.
If you have a designer that does not have much knowledge of PHP or Magento you can simply point him/her to this file and tell him/her to do his/her magic.
If you output everything from a class method someone might get confused.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it explained exactly what I wanted to know and went a step further to help me with the view.